# File upload in mean stack

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean

I am new to mean, I am trying to upload a file in my project but I am not able to find any suitable way for uploading I am making a project using Yeoman generator crud(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-mean1/index.html).  I did a lot of  research. tell me how to do and and what all files I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of uploading files in a mean app is by using **Multer**
check this link: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: thanks for reply, I visited the link but can you suggest me some more link where i can learn to upload file step by step i.e what change i have to do and which file to change.